# Does upcasting a null pointer lead to undefined behavior

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, nullptr, upcasting

I'm wondering whether the following code leads to undefined behavior:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

struct IA { 
  virtual ~IA() {}
  int a = 0;
};
struct IB {
  virtual ~IB() {}
  int b = 0;
};
struct C: IA, IB {};

int main() {
  C* pc = nullptr;
  IB* pib = pc;
  std::printf("%p %p", (void*)pc, (void*)pib);
}
```

Comment: This generates `0 0` using c++ 14: https://ideone.com/iefRnb

Comment: An example with multiple inheritance (and thus pointer adjustment) would be even more interesting.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed. Gonna update the question.

Comment: [Well it keeps up](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab274ff2d68443c5).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stroustrup discusses this case in section 4.5 of [his 1989 multiple inheritance paper [PDF]](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/compsystems/1989/fall_stroustrup.pdf):

> The solution is to elaborate the conversion (casting) operation to
>   test for the pointer-value 0 [...]
>
> The added complexity and run-time overhead are a test and an
>   increment.

The implementation checks explicitly for null-values and ensures that the result of the cast is still a null-value. This was true in C++98 and has not changed with C++11 and `nullptr`.

This is especially important in the case of multiple base classes, where a cast from a derived class to one of the base classes might require changing the actual value of the pointer.

In your example, the layout of `C` in memory will first contain the bytes for `IA`, followed by the bytes for `IB`. Casting to `IA` is trival, as a pointer to the beginning of `C` will also point to the beginning of the `IA` part of `C`. Casting to `IB` on the other hand, requires shifting the `C` pointer by the size of `IA`. Performing this shifting in the nullptr case would lead to a non-null pointer after the cast, hence the special treatment for nulls.

As [pointed out by aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29850922/577603), the relevant section in the standard is [conv.ptr] §4.10:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `B`”, where `B` is a base
>   class [...] of `D`. [...] The result of the conversion is a pointer to
>   the base class subobject of the derived class object. The null pointer
>   value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

Comment: Your answer provides valuable insights into the implementation. Very nice job!

Comment: @Lingxi Thanks :) I really like that paper by Stroustrup. It is tremendously useful for understanding how a compiler actually deals with multiple inheritance under the hood.

Comment: It would be best if you could update your answer with a reference to the standard (like what @aschepler did). An understanding of both the pedantic standard and some practical implementation issues is nice.

Answer (score 9):

Upcasting a null pointer is well-defined to give you another null pointer:

4.10p3:

> A prvalue of type "pointer to *cv* `D`", where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to *cv* `B`", where `B` is a base class of `D`.  ...  The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.